# Free Schooling for children of parents with work permit in Canada

Tags: canada

I'm going to become a postdoctoral researcher at a Canadian University. Although, my research-related expenses are covered by the University, I won't be receiving any salary for my position.

My question is given that I have a 6-year old daughter, can my daughter benefit from free education in Canada or I'm responsible for her educational expenses?

Answer (score 1):

This being the Dominion of Canada, it would depend on what province you're in but, generally, you'd be able to enroll the child in either the public or separate system (and language system, which, *this being Canada*, varies from province to province).   You would be paying for it out of your property taxes (or, more likely, indirectly by your landlord paying out of his property taxes).

If the university is half-way competent, which is a big if, they will have a foreign student department which should be able to give you assistance on settling in, which would include guidance on this very matter.  In addition, they should be able to provide assistance about taxation, including income tax.